# Residence Permit for retired economically inactive American long term stay in the Netherlands

Tags: resident-permit

I am a retired self-sufficent American female who wishes to move to the Netherlands.  Can I apply for a Residence Permit without having to live with a relative in the Netherlands?  If so, which Residence Permit do I need to submit?

Comment: I suggest you begin your research by visiting this English-language Netherlands government page: https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands, which contains a link for "Staying in the Netherlands for longer than 90 days (long-stay visa)."

Answer (score 1):

Going through the [Visas for the Netherlands](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands) link provided by @David, I could not find a condition that fits your situation

- **retired self-sufficent**

The nearest is **independent entrepreneur**, which does not apply in your case.

---

Assuming that a **retired self-sufficent** category also exists, you would have to apply here:

- [Applying for a long-stay visa (MVV) for residents of the United States | United States | netherlandsandyou.nl](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/your-country-and-the-netherlands/united-states/travel-and-residence/applying-for-a-long-stay-visa-mvv)

> If you want to stay in the Netherlands for longer than 90 days, you may need a residence permit. In many cases you will also have to apply for a long-stay visa before you travel to the Netherlands. This visa is also called an authorisation for temporary stay (MVV).
>
> In the United States, you can apply for this visa at the Netherlands embassy in Washington or at the consulates-general in Miami, New York or San Francisco.
>   ...
>   **in person at a Dutch embassy or consulate.**
>   - **independent entrepreneur** [assumption **retired self-sufficent** is also possible]
>
> > You should apply to the Dutch embassy or consulate in person. You should make the appointment yourself. Below you can read how to do this in your country.

For such an interview, I would advise you to be prepared to be able to supply the following information:

- where in the Netherlands you wish to live

  - for a cost of living estimate
- regular monthly income

  - documented in a varifiable way
- a realistic monthly cost of a mandatory health insurance

  - [Health insurance and residence permit | Health insurance | Government.nl](https://www.government.nl/topics/health-insurance/health-insurance-and-residence-permit)

Since a private health insurance can be very costly, the resulting sum will probably the **desiding** factor. This assumption is based on my personal experience with a Canadian friend who retired to Berlin.